# Apache server ends up "blacklinsting" browsers

Tags: server, apache2

I've installed Zurmo CRM on Ubuntu 16.04 server on a server (OVH Virtual Private Server -KVM OpenStack, 1 vCore(s), 2,4 GHz, 4 Go RAM, 20 Go SSD - way above the app requirements).
It works perfectly fine for a couple of uses, but after a while some screens, maybe heaver than others, freeze during 120s then say "Sorry".
When I restart apache(2) or wait those 2 minutes, the CRM is back online but those screens will have the same behavior.

Here is the funny part: when I try with another browser, I can access the faulty screens during a fiew minutes/uses until the app freez again ... and will no longer be available on the newly tested brother.
It's like if after a couple of uses, the browsers were "blacklisted" by the server, for those screens ...
It was the same for Chrome then Edge then Firefox then Chrome "Incognito" ... now none of them can access those screens...

I've been working on the php.ini but it showed no effect.
Any idea?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try to find system logs and check if some info about the errors.

The "faulty screens" are consulting some Database, can be the workload to heavy and provoke a timeout?